# como puedo enviar datos recibidos de una peticion post en una peticion get en Angular

Tags: angular, api

Estoy haciendo una peticion post a una api, esta api me devuelve un access token que debo incluir en la peticion get para poder obtener los datos. Estoy intentando con el objeto HttpHeaders, se que es un objeto inmutable, pero no he podido encontrar la manera para poder insertar los valores que me devuelve la peticion post. intente tambien creando un objeto simple, como lo hago con el objeto "parametros" pero no me deja, me da error. lo que quiero es poder insertar los valores token_type y access_token que me devuelve la petición post en unas cabeceras que pueda enviar en la petetcion GEt para poder obtener los datos, como podria hacerlo? aquí esta mi código:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HostlistService {

    cabecera = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': ''
    }

    parametros = {
      'grant_type':'client_credentials',
      'client_id': 1,
      'client_secret': 'clientSecret'
    }


  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

  }

  obtenerToken(){
    return this.http.post<any>('URL/oauth/token',this.parametros).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.cabecera.Accept=result.token_type;
        this.cabecera.Authorization=result.access_token;
      },error =>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  obtenerInmuebles(){
    return this.http.get('URL',this.cabecera);
  }

}
```

foto donde muestro que los parametros no se envian al hacer la peticion GET:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HostlistService {

    cabecera = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': ''
    }

    parametros = {
        'grant_type':'client_credentials',
        'client_id': 1,
        'client_secret': 'clientSecret'
    }


    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

    }

    obtenerToken(){
        return this.http.post<any>('URL/oauth/token',this.parametros,).subscribe(
            result => {
                // El resultado de token_type es 'Bearer' que no es un valor válido para la cabecera Accept. 
                // Esta para lo que se usa es para concatenarse con el token y conformar el header Authorization 
                this.cabecera.Authorization= result.token_type + ' ' + result.access_token;
            }, error =>{
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }

    obtenerInmuebles(){
        // Los incluyes usando las opciones de http en los headers
        return this.http.get('URL', {headers: this.cabecera});
    }

}
```

Los get no tienen `body` por lo que el último argumento son todas las opciones que puedes ponerle a la petición, entre ellas los `headers`.

El header `Autorization` cuando se usa con bearer tokens debe ser siempre algo como `Bearer <token>`

Comment: El error ya no lo muestra, pero revisando en la consola del navegador, cuando hago click en peticion veo que no se estan enviando los parametros.

Comment: @JulianProg Por favor revisa bien porque el código está correcto. A que petición te refieres cuando dices los parámetros?

Comment: Me refiero a la peticion GET, acabo de editar mi pregunta y subí una foto para que lo veas, no se envían los parametros.

Comment: @JulianProg no vas a poder ver nada en parámetros porque tu autorization se esta enviando en la cabecera de la petición y si no se envía dicho autorization podrías inicializar la cabecera en el constructor de tu service y así dejarlo disponible para n cantidad de peticiones desees realizar

Comment: No entiendo. cuando hago la peticion POST si puedo ver los parametros, por que con la peticion GET no? que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: @JulianProg Lo que llamas parámetros son en Mozilla los de la query o el body, o sea `http://url/path?param=value`, es `param` el único parámetro. El post lo que manda es body. Lo que mandas en tu petición get va en las `Cabeceras`, revisa ahí.

Comment: Ok, revise, y lo que veo es que "Authorization" no tiene nada, esta vació. la asignación que hago dentro de ObtenerToken no se esta guardando, y no entiendo porque. cuándo hago el console.log en el ObtenerToken si me me lo muestra, pero si lo hago dentro de OtenerInmuebles no muestra nada.

Comment: Cuando ejecutas la llamada de ObtenerToken lo que podrías hacer es guardar la info que te retorna en el [session storage](https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/) y dentro de ObtenerInmuebles tomas los valores de ese session para formar tu autorization y formar el header que viajará en tu peticion

Comment: Para esto no tengo que usar httpinterceptors? o no es necesario? estoy leyendo para tratar de conseguir informacion ya que no he podido resolver nada, estoy atascado y encontre uin articulo que hablar sobre eso.

Comment: @JulianProg `Authorization` debe estar lleno si llamaste a `obtenerToken` primero y luego a `obtenerInmuebles` y sólo estará presente en este último. Si, deberías utilizar interceptors pero para eso necesitas un servicio adicional que almacene el token y que se utilize en todos y cada uno de los servicios que llaman al API.

Comment: @devconcept la implementación correcta debería ser usando interceptors? como lo estoy haciendo sería una mala forma de implementación?

Comment: @JulianProg es lo ideal porque si intentas luego dividir tu servicio con llamadas http en varios servicios cada una de las instancias tendria que obtener un token lo cual genera una gran cantidad de problemas en si mismo.